# Arduino IDE compiles, UECIDE not

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors, uecide

I'm rewriting a personal project and it doesn't compile under UECIDE 0.9.1, but it does with Arduino IDE 1.8.5.

Target is NodeMCU 0.9 with default options.

**Arduino IDE 1.8.5**

```
Archiving built core (caching) in: /tmp/arduino_cache_347503/core/core_esp8266_esp8266_nodemcu_CpuFrequency_80,UploadSpeed_115200,FlashSize_4M3M_4a642491bde0820b9be0f8ad42686d29.a
Sketch uses 299199 bytes (28%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 37372 bytes (45%) of dynamic memory, leaving 44548 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
```

**UECIDE 0.9.1**

```
• Error at line 231 in file Monitor.ino:
‣ expected '{' before ';' token

• Error at line 231 in file Monitor.ino:
‣ expected ')' before ';' token

• Error at line 190 in file Monitor.ino:
‣ redefinition of 'CronEntry cronBlink'

• Error at line 231 in file Monitor.ino:
‣ 'CronEntry cronBlink' previously declared here
```

Project is too large to post here, so I zipped it and uploaded to Google Drive, where anyone can download it with this link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BGvqtPx0547fPfX1Nucwhd_a-MO__vWX/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT**
(After lambda comment by Majenko)

I was using a struct to hold cron entries, using lambdas:

```
struct CRON_ENTRY {
  boolean active;       // Task is active.
  unsigned long start;  // Start time (ms uptime).
  unsigned long repeat; // Repeat every (ms). 
  fcncron fcn;          // task.
};

CRON_ENTRY cronBlink = {false, 0,   500, [](CRON_ENTRY * c)
{
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    display.countdownPanel();
}
```

and then replace CRON_ENTRY struct with CronEntry class:

```
CronEntry cronBlink(false, 0,   500, []() {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    display.countdownPanel();});
```

I really like lambas because they made code shorter.

Comment: ESP8266 support is shaky at best. They keep changing things randomly and breaking things. Time for yet another overhaul of the core...

Comment: Actually, this is a problem with UECIDE itself - or rather with the INO parsing routine. You have a lambda function in a constructor, and it really doesn't like that (the CronEntry constructors). Consider moving those to normal functions instead.

Comment: I need to rework the parser so it can handle lambda functions. I'll make it my top priority. It needs an overhaul anyway.

Comment: Labdas are not something I have really worked with much. I prefer to keep my code in easy to manage blocks, and labdas confuse the hell outta me ;)

Comment: UECIDE has a GitHub Issues page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in UECIDE. It doesn't like lambda functions in constructors.

A complete rewrite of the sketch parser to use Exuberant Ctags is under way.

Comment: I thought that UECIDE and Arduino IDE have different front ends (UI) and the same back end (compiler and tools). Can you explain how they are different?

Comment: There are three layers to both. The IDE (editor), the parser (which converts the INO into a CPP file) and the compiler. Only the compiler is the same.